# Impact of annihilators in C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. Let $S\subseteq  A$. We put $$\operatorname{Ann}_r(S)=\{a\in A : \forall  s\in S,~ ~as=0\}$$

Suppose that $A$ satisfies  the following property:

For every  $S\subseteq  A$ there is a projection $q\in A$ such that
$\operatorname{Ann}_r(S)=Aq$.

> Q. Is $A$ necessarily a von Neumann algebra?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An AW${}^*$-algebra is a C${}^*$-algebra which satisfies this condition for both right and left annihilators. So every AW${}^*$-algebra has your property, and any C${}^*$ algebra that is isomorphic to its opposite algebra has your property iff it is AW${}^*$.

There are lots of AW${}^*$-algebras that aren't von Neumann algebras, even in the commutative case.